# Ordinal exponentiation identity with natural sum of exponents

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, exponentiation, ordinals

This is related to a previous question on [How to think about ordinal exponentiation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278992/how-to-think-about-ordinal-exponentiation)

One possible definition for the natural product $\alpha\otimes\beta$ of ordinals is based on Cantor Normal Forms and natural sum: if $\alpha=\omega^{\alpha_1}+\cdots+\omega^{\alpha_n}$ and $\beta=\omega^{\beta_1}+\cdots+\omega^{\beta_m}$ are CNFs, then
$\alpha\otimes\beta=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\bigoplus_{j=1}^m\omega^{\alpha_i\oplus\beta_j}$.

With this definition, one automatically gets the following exponentiation law for natural products of exponentials: $\omega^\alpha\otimes\omega^\beta=\omega^{\alpha\oplus\beta}$.

*My question:* does it more generally hold that $\gamma^\alpha\otimes\gamma^\beta=\gamma^{\alpha\oplus\beta}$ for any $\gamma>0$? And if yes what do you recommend as a good reference?

I expected to find the answer on [wikipedia page on ordinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations) or on some other widely available source but did not manage.

Comment: I *think* the answer is "yes". See the bottom of p. 354 of [*The Cartesian product of sets and the Hessenberg natural product of ordinals*](https://eudml.org/doc/13142) by Hilbert Levitz (1979). To you or anyone else interested in ordinal arithmetic, my advice would be to get ahold of Sierpinski's book **Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers**.

Comment: The bottom of p.354 only mentions $\omega$-exponentiation. What about an arbitrary $\gamma$ (with arbitrary $\alpha$ and $\beta$) ? NB: as is standard, exponentiation is defined inductively with $\gamma^0=1$, $\gamma^{\alpha+1}=\gamma^\alpha.\gamma$, and $\gamma^{\sup_i \lambda_i}=\sup_i \gamma^{\lambda_i}$.

Comment: I'll look in my copy of Sierpinski's book (at home; I'm at work now) this evening or tomorrow morning, and maybe in some other books as well, although if it's not in Sierpinski I doubt I'll find it elsewhere. I'll let you know tomorrow what I find.

Comment: Am I hallucinating or is the claim just wrong ?!?! Since $2=1\oplus 1$, the claim would entail $\alpha\cdot\alpha=\alpha^2=\alpha\otimes\alpha$ which does not hold in general (it holds for $\alpha=\omega$ and other simple cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO: it does not generally hold that $\gamma^\alpha\otimes\gamma^\beta=\gamma^{\alpha\oplus\beta}$.

For example, taking $\alpha=\beta=1$, we don't have $\gamma\otimes\gamma=\gamma^2$. Try it for $\gamma=\omega^2+\omega+1$. This gives
$$\begin{aligned}\gamma^2=\gamma\cdot\gamma&=(\omega^2+\omega+1)\cdot \omega^2 +
(\omega^2+\omega+1)\cdot\omega +
(\omega^2+\omega+1) \\&=
\omega^4+\omega^3+(\omega^2+\omega+1)\end{aligned}$$ while
$\gamma\otimes\gamma =\omega^4+\omega^3\cdot 2+\omega^2\cdot 3+\omega\cdot 2+1$.

One only has $\gamma^\alpha\otimes\gamma^\beta\geq\gamma^{\alpha\oplus\beta}$ in general.

PS: It seems that the equality holds (for any exponents $\alpha$ and $\beta$) when $\gamma$ is a principal ordinal (also called indecomposable ordinal, of the form $\omega^\delta$) and also when it is a finite ordinal. I previously thought that it also holds when $\gamma$ is a finite multiple of an indecomposable ordinal, which would be a common generalization of the two cases, but even this does not work: take e.g. $\gamma=\omega 2$ and $\alpha=\beta=\omega+1$.

Comment: $\gamma^2=\omega^4+\omega^3+\omega^2+\omega+1$ (there are no coefficients equal to $2$).

Comment: (And principal ordinals are more commonly called (additively) indecomposable.)

Comment: ooops. Yes $(\omega^2+\omega+1)^2$ is only $\omega^4+\omega^3+\omega^2+\omega+1$. Thanks for spotting the error. One should not try to think about exponentiation before understanding multiplication. Will edit the above answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have an answer to your question, but I did search through quite a few set theory books this morning and I made notes of what I found in case you or others are interested.

The topic seems less covered in books than I expected, and I suspect you'll have to consult journal articles to find much of significance (unless you can read Hessenberg's and Jacobsthal's papers in their original German). To this end, a google search for all of the words [Hessenberg natural sum product](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hessenberg+natural+sum+product) is the most useful search I know of for finding something if you're not able to search in a university library. I haven't had time today to do much searching for journal papers, and of the few papers I found, **[9]** and **[10]** seemed to be the most relevant, but I don't think they have anything *specifically* relevant to your question. The only math StackExchange post I found was [When the ordinal sum equals the Hessenberg (“natural”) sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386274/when-the-ordinal-sum-equals-the-hessenberg-natural-sum), but I didn't look very hard.

**[1]** Heinz Bachmann, **Transfinite Zahlen** [Transfinite Numbers], 2nd edition, Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete #1, Springer-Verlag, 1967, viii + 228 pages.

> See §23. *Natürliche Operationen* (pp. 107-112). The bottom of p. 109 has an identity that is what you want, but it appears to be for a natural product defined by Jacobsthal rather than the natural product as defined by Hessenberg.

**[2]** Abraham Adolf [Adolph] Halevi Fraenkel, **Abstract Set Theory**, 2nd edition, Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics, 1961, viii + 295 pages.

> A 1966 3rd edition (viii + 297 pages) exists, but I don't have a copy of it. See Chapter III, §11, last two pages of Section 4. *Arithmetic of Ordinals*, pp. 214-215.

**[3]** Felix Hausdorff, **Set Theory**, Chelsea Publishing Company, 1957, 352 pages.

> This is a translation by John R. Aumann and others of the 1935 German edition. See Chapter IV, last two pages of §14. *The Combining of Ordinal Numbers*, pp. 80-81.

**[4]** Michael Holz, Karsten Steffens, and Edmund [Edi] Weitz, **Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic**, Birkhäuser Advanced Texts, Birkhäuser Verlag, 1999, viii + 304 pages.

> See Chapter 1, near the end of Section 4. *Arithmetic of Ordinals*, p. 37. Only Hessenberg's natural sum is considered.

**[5]** Erich Kamke, **Theory of Sets**, Dover Publications, 1950, viii + 144 pages.

> This is a translation by Frederick Otto Bagemihl of the 1947 2nd German edition. See Chapter IV, last two pages of §10. *Polynomials in Ordinal Numbers*, pp. 109-110.

**[6]** Azriel Levy, **Basic Set Theory**, Perspectives in Mathematical Logic, Springer-Verlag, 1979, xiv + 391 pages.

> Reprinted by Dover Publications in 2002 (xiv + 398 pages). The Dover edition includes roughly 200 Corrections and Additions in an appendix on pp. 393-398. See Chapter IV, end of Section 2. *Ordinal Exponentiation*, p. 130, Definition 2.21 and Exercise 2.22. Only Hessenberg's natural sum is considered.

**[7]** Horst Wolfram Pohlers, **Proof Theory. An Introduction**, Lecture Notes in Mathematics #1407, Springer-Verlag, 1989, viii + 213 pages.

> A later edition exists, but I don't have a copy of it. See Chapter I, near the end of §7. *Ordinal arithmetic*, p. 43. Only Hessenberg's natural sum is considered.

**[8]** Waclaw Franciszek Sierpinski, **Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers**, 2nd edition revised, Monografie Matematyczne #34, PWN--Polish Scientific Publishers, 1965, 491 pages.

> See Chapter XIV, Section 28: *Natural sum and natural product of ordinal numbers* (pp. 366-367). Despite how thorough this book is, surprisingly little is said about this topic.

**[9]** Philip Wilkinson Carruth, [*Arithmetic of ordinals with applications to the theory of ordered Abelian groups*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183504256), **Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society** 48 #4 (April 1942), 262-271.

**[10]** Martin Michael Zuckerman, [*Natural sums of ordinals*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm77/fm77130.pdf), **Fundamenta Mathematicae** 77 #3 (1973), 289-294.

*(ADDED 31 MONTHS LATER)* A few days ago I happened to come across two more items of possible interest.

**[11]** Rastislav Telgársky, [*Derivatives of Cartesian product and dispersed spaces*](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-cmv19i1n10), **Colloquium Mathematicum** 19 #1 (1968), 59-66.

> **(first few sentences of the paper)** This paper contains some topological applications of Hessenberg's natural sum of ordinal numbers. Algebraic properties of this operation were studied by Sikorski in [3]. Our Theorem 1 generalizes the known formula for the derivative, i.e. the set of limit points, of a cartesian product of sets in topological spaces. Theorem 2 gives a topological definition of the natural sum and some applications to dispersed spaces. Finally, we give conditions under which the derivative of a set is closed and other related facts as well as proofs of the theorems. It seems that it [= this paper] is the first time that Hessenberg's sum [has] found an application apparently distant from its definition.

**[12]** Roman Sikorski, [*On an ordered algebraic field*](http://rcin.org.pl/dlibra/docmetadata?id=16727&from=publication), **Sprawozdania z posiedzeń Towarzystwa Naukowego Warszawskiego, Wydział III** (nauk matematyczno-zycznych), Warszawa [= Comptes Rendus des Séances de la Société des Sciences et des Lettres de Varsovie, Classe III (Sciences Mathématiques et Physiques)] 41 (1948), 69-96.

> The algebraic properties of both the natural sum and the natural product seems to be mostly confined to pp. 77-78, but later pages *might* have some things of interest to someone only interested in the natural sum and natural product. (I didn't look very closely at the later pages.) I don't think the question that phs asked is answered in Sikorski's paper, but again, I did not spend much time looking at Sikorski's paper.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these pointers. It is always surprising to see how what seems like a simple & natural question on classic topics is not readily answered by the standard literature.

Comment: "*simple & natural question*" -- Pun not intended?

Comment: Hi Dave, the results on ordinal "sums" in Carruth's paper were rediscovered later, in G.H. Toulmin. *[Shuffling ordinals and transfinite dimension](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-4/1/177.full.pdf)*, Proc. London Math. Soc. (3), **4**, (1954), 177–195. [MR0065907 (16,502a)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=65907).

Comment: @Andrés E. Caicedo: FYI, I almost certainly have a copy of this paper, because I went through all the issues of this journal 7 or 8 years ago and my filter for what to photocopy was definitely weak enough to have caught this. However, those papers are still in the original [folders](http://blog.printpapa.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/118_2547794.jpg) I put them in as I was photocopying them, stacked up somewhere and not yet filed away according to topic, otherwise I would have come across it in my binders of papers on arithmetic of ordinal numbers.

Comment: @Dave I thought that might be the case. I only learned of Carruth's yesterday, had been previously attributing these results to Toulmin. (Once this happened, I figured you probably had something around here on the topic...)